x server setup for running application spanning multiple monitors
I noticed that it is possible to run linux programs on a specific display, using the
DISPLAY:<display-number>.
I want to run a simple tkinter application that spans the entire width of multiple screens on an ubuntu setup. Is there a way to achieve this using cli? It will be super cumbersome to drag the window over the screens manually. Want to avoid this at all means possible

What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].
